# Reading data from Excel sheet containg multiple tables using C#

Tags: c#, excel

Let's say I have an Excel file contains one sheet, and in this sheet there is 2 tables one for employee with fields [empID,empName,title] and another table for department with fields [deptId,deptName].

I want to know how can I read data from that Excel file and load both tables in datatables, one for `emplyee` and the other for `department`.

I have searched and find that I can query through sheet by "select * from [sheet$]" after making an oleDbconnection with Excel but in my case the sheet contains two tables different in structure.

I am working on a Windows application using VS2010 C#.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make a SheetSelectionForm. Then put these codes on your form, and call `PopulateSheetsOfExcelFile(excelFilePath)` method. This Form will show you to names of Excel sheets and you can select which sheet you want to read from Excel.

As you say, these tables have different structure, so you need to make different DataTables for each sheet of Excel.

There is another way to read whole Excel with DataAdapter. With my method, you create custom DataTable, and fill that with giving excel column/row index.

```
using System.Data.OleDb;


private void SelectItem() 
        { 
            ExcelSheetName = excelSheetsListBox.SelectedItem != null ? 
                excelSheetsListBox.SelectedItem.ToString() : string.Empty; 
            Close(); 
        }

private void PopulateSheetsOfExcelFile(string excelFilePath) 
        { 
            try 
            { 
                String connString = string.Empty;

                try 
                { 
                                      connString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;\"", excelFilePath); 
                    using (OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(connString)) 
                    { 
                        objConn.Open(); 
                        using (DataTable dt = objConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null)) 
                        { 
                            if (dt == null) 
                                return;

                            excelSheetsListBox.Items.Clear();

                            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) 
                            { 
                                DataRow row = dt.Rows[i]; 
                                excelSheetsListBox.Items.Add(row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString()); 
                            } 
                        } 
                    } 
                } 
                catch (Exception exA1) 
                { 
                                        connString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\"", excelFilePath); 
                    using (OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(connString)) 
                    { 
                        objConn.Open(); 
                        using (DataTable dt = objConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null)) 
                        { 
                            if (dt == null) 
                                return;

                            excelSheetsListBox.Items.Clear();

                            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) 
                            { 
                                DataRow row = dt.Rows[i]; 
                                excelSheetsListBox.Items.Add(row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString()); 
                            } 
                        } 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
            catch (Exception ex) 
            { 
               MessageBox.Show(“HATA”);

                ExcelSheetName = string.Empty; 
                Close(); 
            } 
        }
```

Comment: thnx serkan i will try ur code and i will get back yo u and let u know if i have any questions or not,,,thnx again

Comment: Ok. The article is written in Turkish, if you dont know Turkish, ask me to translate.

Comment: i wana ask u about something in the code u have posted ,,,what do u mean by // excelSheetsListBox.Items.Add(row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString()); 

what do u mean by ["table_name"]??

Comment: This code line will add Excel Sheet Names to your excelSheetsListBox.

Comment: i wana ask u about something is ur code displays the sheetnames in excelSheetListBox only,,i want to load the data in the 2 tables in two datatables ,,and bind each data table to grid ,,,my sheet contains 2 tables with different structure ,i wana know how can i query inside the sheet to get the data for each table

Comment: Understand. I dont know any query that can make your question. My codes just make, SheetSelection, and Fill DataTable with your objects. SheetSelectionForm can help you with you can create required DT for selected sheet (because you have differnt structure)